# Run plist command every 5 seconds

Tags: launchd, filesystem, plist, xml

I have the following plist file in my User/Library/LaunchAgents folder. It presses the "g" key every 60 seconds.

My question is, how can I change this to press the "g" key every 5 seconds?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/usr/bin/osascript</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>osascript</string>
        <string>-e</string>
        <string>tell application "System Events" to keystroke "g"</string>
    </array>
    <key>ServiceDescription</key>
    <string>Auto Keypress</string>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Second</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: See my answer below. But why do you want such a thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the plist to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>G-key-pusher</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/usr/bin/osascript</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/bin/sh</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>sh</string>
        <string>-c</string>
        <string>while sleep 5; do /usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "g"'; done</string>
    </array>
    <key>ServiceDescription</key>
    <string>Auto Keypress</string>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

What it does, is to run a shell script that does the 5 second timer and calls osascript. The launchd plist just ensures the script is restarted if it were to die for some reason. Please note that I still haven't tested this, but I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work. Though I have had problems in the past when changing launchd items, which I fixed by changing the label. Which reminds me, you had omitted the value for the `Label` key in your plist.

(Edit: Explain a little, and provide a complete file instead of explaining what parts need to be changed.)

Comment: thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I'm unable to get this working. It won't press "g" at all, in any application. I replaced the key Program through the first closing array with your first code block. I also replaced the key Second and integer 0 with your second code block. When I run the file nothing happens. Any chance you can take a look at this and post a complete code example?

Comment: @Ryan: Sorry, I've been insanely busy, or else I would have tested and posted a complete example. You need to replace the whole of the StartCalendarInterval key and the accompanying dict with the second code block in my answer. Holler if you still can't get it to work, and I'll make a complete example when I can find some spare minutes.

Comment: @Ryan: I edited my answer and added some comments. Still not tested.

Comment: I just tested this and it presses the g key every 10 seconds, which is good enough for me. Thank you!

Comment: Okay … every 10 seconds? That's beyond weird, unless the osascript bit actually takes 5 seconds to execute. But if it works, it works.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen actually not that weird. OSX expects background processes to run for at least 10s, and so polls the KeepAlive once every 10s. The "sleep 5" here actually does not increase frequency of anything, just adds delay. 

HOWEVER, if you put the "hit G" code before AND after the "sleep 5" then you will achieve OP's aim.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a very old thread but it came up in one of my recent searches for launchctl advice so I wanted to include the correct answer launching every "x" seconds.
launchctl can be used like cron (only better). In your original script, you use the key "StartCalendarInterval". You should simply use the key "StartInterval" and give it the number of seconds.

Replace your lines:

```
<key>StartCalendarInterval</key> <dict>
    <key>Second</key>
    <integer>0</integer> </dict>
```

With:

```
<key>StartInterval</key>
<integer>5</integer>
<key>ThrottleInterval</key>
<integer>0</integer>
```